# I have a bespoke webfont that only works on Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, fonts

I have a bespoke font for a client which I converted into a webfont. All went fine, works on my mac and others across Firefox, Safari and Chrome, however when viewed using Windows, the font becomes extremely distorted and unreadable, on any browser.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Could it be an issue within the original font or is there a code trick I can use to fix this?

Comment: Did you test the original font on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

It's a hinting problem. Microsoft’s rasteriser tries to align characters to whole pixel grid.

Read: https://www.typotheque.com/articles/hinting